# Device with multiple corresponding registration tokens not receiving notification

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

User Installs app and login through user **A** 
now the token key is generated for the device and sent to application server.
again user uninstalled the app and reinstall it and this time user logged in through user **B** again a different token is generated and sent to server.

Now the problem is both user contains different token key for the same device, when server calls the google for push notification the app doesn't receives any message. which was working previously.

any help would be appericiated

Comment: Did u delete the previous token generated by user A and insert the new token  generated by user B?

Comment: how do i delete that

Comment: Every time your app is uninstalled, you should, as much as possible, delete the corresponding registration token from your server. Nonetheless, if multiple registration tokens were generated for a single app instance (single device), the GCM server should be returning a [Canonical ID](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration#canonical-ids) that you can use.

Comment: You should have got the notification for the B user. As per your que your server has both the token but your app has only one user active and that should be handle by app only..

Comment: no @ArpitPatel  i am not getting any notification

Comment: @AL. can you please explain in more detail about Canonical IDs.
I Read it in GCM documentation but didn't get it much

Comment: If how I understand your situation is correct, when you are sending a notification to the old registration tokens (from the app instance that uninstalled), the GCM response should return a Canonical ID which is the most recent registration token and should be the one that is used and saved. On a simpler note, the canonical id is just a registration token.

Comment: ok  @AL. let me try this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the previous token generated by user A and insert the new token generated by user B in the application server.

You can send the device ID along with token while registering in the database and overwrite the token value to that corresponding device ID so that only one token will exist for a device.

Comment: that can be a possibility I guess,I will try this and let you know if it works